# simplifying my function calling in python by some type of aggregation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code for a 5 nodes blockchain simulator and I would like to simplify it:

```
node1 = Node(1, 1)
node2 = Node(2, 1)
node3 = Node(3, 1)
node4 = Node(4, 0)
node5 = Node(5, 0)

block1 = Block(1)
block2 = Block(2)

node1.store(block1)
node2.store(block1)
node3.store(block1)
node4.store(block1)
node5.store(block1)

node1.store(block2)
node2.store(block2)
node3.store(block2)
node4.store(block2)
node5.store(block2)

node1.printLastZxid()
node2.printLastZxid()
node3.printLastZxid()
node4.printLastZxid()
node5.printLastZxid()
```

Is there any way to simplify this? Something like

```
for n in range(5):
  node[n].store(block1)
  node[n].printLastZxid()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
nodes=[node1,node2,node3,node4,node5]
for node in nodes:
    node.store(block1)
    node.printLastZxid()
```